# How to align inline img href with text tag it's in?

Tags: html, css, image, inline

I have an `<a>` tag inside a `<h4>` tag, so any text displayed in the `<a>` tag has the style from the h4 and is inline with it.

How can I vertically align all of these elements? I haven't really displayed `<a>` tags in this way before.

Comment: What do you mean by perfectly inline?  Do you want them on separate lines with the left sides aligning?  Or do you want them to be on the same line but aligned in the middle of the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood this properly just add this to your css:

```
img {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vyhb4fh/14/)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to apply the [vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) property to the images.

```
<h4>
    <a href=""><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hiXucbv.png" style="vertical-align:middle"></a>
    hit
    <a href=""><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hiXucbv.png" style="vertical-align:middle">user</a>
    and did something.
</h4>
```

[Here's the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hosLz2w/).

Answer (score 2):

There are more than one way to do this. Tables or Divs are two methods.
It requires a bit more html code.

How to vertically do this in a table is the fastest. Place each item in a separate table cell:

```
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
  <tr>

      <td align=center valign=middle><img here></td>

      <td align=center valign=middle><h1><a href=''>Text Here</a></h1></td>

      <td align=center valign=middle><a href=''>Text Here</a></td>

      <td align=center valign=middle><a href=''><img here></a></td>

      <td align=center valign=middle><img here></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're asking, I think you just want to apply the style `vertical-align: middle`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/acjohnson55/2dL0js7f/)

Html:

```
<h4>
    <a href=""><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hiXucbv.png"></a>
    hit
    <a href=""><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hiXucbv.png">user</a>
    and did something.
</h4>
```

CSS:

```
h4 img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by perfectly in-line. What I understood by your description

> but changing things like line-height only seems to mess up the formatting on the page.

you want the images to be middle aligned vertically and need some space between second image and "user".

I would suggest using padding instead of using   as it is not a good practice to use it.

```
a{ text-decoration: none; }
img{ vertical-align: middle; }
img.padded{ padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px; }

<h4>
    <a href=""><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hiXucbv.png"></a>hit
    <a href=""><img class="padded" src="http://i.imgur.com/hiXucbv.png">user</a>and did something.
</h4>
```

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/anujtyagi/9gL64Lt9/

Hope this answers your question.